# Two Network Interfaces - One for LAN and One For Internet

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, routing, lan

I am using 2 connections on my Windows 10 PC. One is for accessing my LAN and other is for internet.

Long story short: What I need is that I prioritize my Internet connection (4G USB stick) for accessing web but when I need to access something over that other LAN (multiple subnets) it is not working.

Basically I need my 4G connection online all the time, and I need to access different subnets over my LAN connection (ethernet port) like I normally do. For instance my PC's subnet over that LAN is 10.79.4.0/24 and I can also access my other subnets 10.79.0.0/24` etc. ... But as soon as I *switch* to my other internet interface (4G USB stick), only my initial subnet over that first LAN interface is accessible 10.79.4.0/24 and not the other ones.

If my metric is lower on the LAN (which is also internet capable over a different firewall and external IP) everything is fine. But, if I lets say just kill the internet over LAN for test purposes, it switches to the second interface (4G USB stick) which is fine, but I cannot access any local resources other then the subnet which that interface is on.

Basically this is my failover method if priority firewall/internet goes off and I want to access the Windows 10 device over TV or RealVNC and the local resources.

How can I do this? I believe it is achievable somehow. I just do not know how can it be done? I hope I made myself clear...

[image]

### Interfaces

#### Primary internet connection and LAN connection

[image: Primary internet connection and LAN connection]

#### Secondary, Failover 4G connection

[image: Secondary, Failover 4G connection]

### Routing Table

[image: Routing table]

### Tracert

[image: Tracert]

Comment: Please append the output of ```ipconfig /all``` to your question for both scenarios (Normal operation / fall back).

Comment: And `route print` as well, please.

Comment: Hi guys, I've just posted what you've asked, looking forward for your reply - thanks!

Comment: @dirdi - I've provided info you asked. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @JorgeValentini see what Ive posted

Comment: @MuWu, Does it work as you expect if you just create persistent routes for the internal networks that you need to access? for instance, if you had 172.16.0.0/16 as one of those "different subnets" you'd use `route -p add 172.16.0.0  mask 255.255.0.0 10.79.4.71`. Can you try that?

Comment: Hi @JorgeValentini , I've tried to add the route while my 4G was active and LAN cable is connected , still after it, I can just access the same subnet 10.79.4.0/24 and  I can only ping devices on that subnet and not other connected subsites, do you have maybe any other suggestions?. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeValentini What I also noticed is when I make tracert for lets say 10.79.0.212 address while its connected to the 4G internet connection and over ethernet for local, it makes tracert through 4G connection - how can I change so that it doesn't go over that interface? - Check the picture above

Comment: first, I made a mistake in the command I sent you, should be `10.79.4.1` instead of `10.79.4.71`, can you test again; regarding your question on the tracert, it makes sense considering the routing table, `10.79.0.212` is not a host in the `10.79.4.0/23`, it goes through the default. to route that run `route -p add 10.79.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.79.4.1`. Note I am just imagining your network segments.

Comment: @JorgeValentini you the man Jorge! this now works! Thanks..Just need to figure out, how to switch metrics to 4G automatically once my primary internet connection goes down and LAN stays on? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I will write an answer to stop bugging you with comments. The environment that you have, from your command outputs looks something like:

[image: Current Environment]

Let me split this in two:

## Routing Step

First let's summarize how the 4G connection would work while still accessing the local network (as confirmed in the question comments). Windows will prefer the route with the lowest metric, in this case LAN is 291 and 4G is 527.

If you change metrics so that your 4G connection kicks in, you should have routes for all of the internal networks you will want to reach:

```
route -p add 10.79.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.79.4.1
...
route -p add <SUBNET IP> mask <MASK> 10.79.4.1
```

Consider that `SUBNET IP` is the network address ([See here](http://ladu.htk.tlu.ee/erika/taavi/doc2/network_and_broadcast_address.html)).

If you have all `10.x.x.x` networks then an easier approach could be to do `route -p add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.79.4.1`. You can do this because your 4G is on `192.168.8.0/24`

## Failover Step

I don't want to say you can't do it, but to the best of my knowledge I don't think you will be able to handle this with just clever metric configuration. This is because for Windows the gateway is up. Windows will automatically switch to a higher metric (default via `192.168.8.1`) only in the case that the lower metric gateway (`10.79.4.1`) is unreachable. However this is not the case, your next hop is alive, you just lost internet connection.

With what you have, I would take the approach of writing a quick and dirty script to change metrics upon internet failure, something like:

```
@echo off

echo Checking internet connection...
ping %1 -n 1 -w 1000 > NUL

if errorlevel 1 (GOTO FALLBACK) else (GOTO ALLGOOD)

:FALLBACK
echo Internet Failed
:: YOUR CODE
echo -- Here goes the code to change the routes and metrics when internet fails
::...
exit 0

:ALLGOOD
echo Internet probe was successful
:: MAYBE REVERSE THE METRICS?
exit 0
```

Store it in a `.cmd` file and paste the routes as you figured them out on the first step. Maybe create a rollback routine as well in the event it comes back. The condition itself works:

[image: Command execution example]

pass the probe IP to test connection as an argument. I would then set it up to run periodically (set intervals depending on your downtime tolerance).

I hope this helps you figure it out.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Jorge, I'll try this and report you with the results. Thanks for your time and effort! You have been very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help sir!